# HTML String to Plain Text using JQUERY for comparison

Tags: c#, jquery

I am facing an issue to covert the HTML string to plain text using jquery for comparing with other string.

The issue appears when I replace HTML string containing ' ' with space. The two strings do not match and return 'false'.

I have given the image link below of console log.

I would really appreciate if someone can help me out.

![Console Log]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7xyN.jpg

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: code is text. Please add text to your question, not pictures. Then people can actually use your code to try and reproduce the issue. Also make sure you include enough relevant data which would demonstrate the issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are more than one character for ' ' (space). `String.fromCharCode(160)` and `String.fromCharCode(32)` looks the same, but are not equal. I guess that's your issue.

The space character from the keyboard id charCode 32, so replace the 160 character from the html to the 32 character, and then compare.

```
var space1 = String.fromCharCode(32);
var space2 = String.fromCharCode(160);
htmlString = htmlString.replace(/space2/g, space1);
```

Comment: Check what's the charCode of the space character in the html - in the console write - `([copy & paste here the char]).charCodeAt(0)`.

Comment: yes. you where right there is difference inthe value I am comparing.

![Console Log]: https://imgur.com/BCVxPLw

Comment: So if you replace all the 160 char to 32 char, is there still a difference?

Comment: Even after replace the charCode is still the same.

![Console Log]: https://imgur.com/KyJYphD

Comment: Hi,
This format is working fine.
str1 = (str1).replace(String.fromCharCode(160), String.fromCharCode(32));

returns true!